# Javascript multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, html, select

I tried searching for an answer to this for a while, but to no avail.

I'm trying to do a simple online calculator (that calculates some photovoltaic panels energy), but I'm stuck in something simple (I'm new to Javascript although I worked with Flash's ActionScript 3.0 for a while).

What I need done is a html select that defines which other select group appears in the page. Something like this (obviously this doesn't work, just setting an example):

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="test1" onclick="checkField()">
<option>Selected A Group</option>
<option>Selected B Group</option>
</select>
<script>//insert second group here</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function checkField(){
var temp = document.getElementById('test1').value;

if(temp === "Selected A Group"){
//insert code to "echo" the first optional select group
} else {
//insert code to "echo" the second optional select group
}
}
```

Sorry if its a bit confusing, but I cant really explain all that well.
Here is an example of what I would want, where selecting a option makes the other fields change accordingly: http://www.toshiba.eu/innovation/download_drivers_bios.jsp

Comment: Your code works,  what does this mean `insert code to "echo" the first optional select group`

Comment: have a look to my answer, even if you have chosen the definetive one already, it contains some practices that can help you understand Javascript better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3GkrX/

Just about the same as Mevins.... changed to switch/case though

html:

```
<select id="test1" id="name" onchange="checkField()">
    <option>----</option>
<option>Selected A Group</option>
<option>Selected B Group</option>
</select>
<div id="optional">Please select!</div>
```

JS:

```
function checkField(){
var temp = document.getElementById('test1').value;

    switch(temp){

        case "Selected A Group":
            document.getElementById("optional").innerHTML="<select name='optionalA'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>";
            break;
        case "Selected B Group":
            document.getElementById("optional").innerHTML="<select name='optionalB'><option>3</option><option>4</option></select>";
            break
            default:
                document.getElementById("optional").innerHTML="Please select!";
            break;

    }

}
```

Also added the second group as a real option, and a default as "please select". may or may not be necessary in your case

Comment: Ah, I did not know about the "innerHTML". In Flash AS3, I just add/remove movieclips to the stage so, being a newcomer to JS, sometimes I don't know how to affect the html from within the JS.
This worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there, actually javascript doesn't "echo" values directly, it does log values using `console.log(your value);` to a debug console, similar to AS2 `trace()` if my memory isn't failing.

To "output" information to the document you should have a look into [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)
When you use document.write it will directly write to the documents end.

The "correct" way would be to create a DOM element, with the elements you want inside it, and then append it to the desired element. Have a look at the comments

```
<!-- Be Aware to use the onchange trigger on select boxes, if you use onclick the function will run, even
if you didn't really chose any option -->
<select id="test1" onchange="checkField()">
<!-- Is good to have a first non-value option, better to trigger the onchange event, if you have 
Select A Group as first option and you click on it, it didn't really "Change", you would have to
pick B Group and then A Group again to trigger the onchange event correctly. -->
<option value="">-- select an option --</option>
<!-- You can have a value attribute on the options, so it's easy to process when programming
while displaying a more detailed description to the users -->
<option value="A">Selected A Group</option>
<option value="B">Selected B Group</option>
</select>

<!-- We create an empty element where we are gonna place the new Select -->
<div id="newSelect"></div>

<!-- By Placing the Javascript on the end of <body>, we ensure that all the DOM elements loaded before running the script -->
<script>
    function checkField(){
        var newSelect = document.getElementById('newSelect'); //targeting container;    
        var temp = document.getElementById('test1').value;

        //Some tasks we do always the option chose is not the first custom one, so we don't have to repeat it
        //on the two If's below
        if(temp !== ""){
            // We remove the select if we placed one already before, so we can add the new one,
            // For example if we chose B Group but changed our mind and Chose A Group later.
            if(oldChild = newSelect.getElementsByTagName('select')[0]){
                oldChild.remove();
            }

            var select = document.createElement("select");
            select.setAttribute('id', 'newSelect');

        }

        if(temp === "A"){
            //you could do JUST:
            //body.innerHTML = "all the html you want in here" instead of all the code following;
            //but all those code is supposed to be the "correct way" of adding elements to the HTML,
            //Google a bit about that for detailed explanations

            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.value = 1;
            option1.text = "Option 1";
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.value = 2;
            option2.text = "Option 2";

            select.appendChild(option1);
            select.appendChild(option2);

            newSelect.appendChild(select);
        } else {
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.value = 3;
            option1.text = "Option 3";
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.value = 4;
            option2.text = "Option 4";

            select.appendChild(option1);
            select.appendChild(option2);

            newSelect.appendChild(select);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Of course there are ways to make this slightly shorter, using loops if your data to ouput has a pattern, but lets do it the "simple" way so you get a grasp of Javascript.

Hope all this helped you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/izAHo
your doing it almost right.

You should put the onclick event on the **option** tag to trigger changes based on the option selected.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>

<select id="test1">
<option onclick="checkField()">Selected A Group</option>
<option>Selected B Group</option>
</select>

<select id="test2">
<option  onclick="check2Field()">Selected C Group</option>
<option>Selected D Group</option>
</select>

<script>//insert second group here</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function checkField(){
var temp = document.getElementById('test1').value;
if(temp === "Selected A Group"){
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML="<option>Selected halloooo Group</option>";
} else {
//insert code to "echo" the second optional select group
}
}
```

Check out my demo for more clarity.